# Linux Server only gets IP Config after first logon

Tags: networking, ssh

I have setup a Linux server and installed openssh server and my application on it.

I configured the IP Connection and was able to ping, ssh to the server.

But as soon as I reboot the server (and the server is up) I can't ping or ssh to the server.

As soon as I locally log on to the server (so not remotely by IP), I'm able to connect by SSH and ping as well.

So somehow the connection can only be setup as soon as a user was logged on locally for the first time.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

Comment: How did you setup your network? does your server has a gui? if so did you setup your network using network manager?

Comment: I did setup with ifconfig eth0, but I didn't setup the /etc/network/interfaces which causes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options you can use to configure your network.  You can use Network Manager or use the /etc/network/interfaces configuration.  The /etc/network/interfaces configuration setup will override the network manager configuration.

I'll give you two options.  Once is for static IP and the other is for a dhcp assigned ip.  Since you are setting up a server where you want to be able to login remotely, I'm assuming that you have a static IP that you will be using.  So you will most likely be more interested in the first one.

First identify your network adapter will will most likely be `eth0` or `eth1`.  I'll use `eth0` for this example.  You can identify the adapter by running `ifconfig` from your current working setup.

**Static IP configuration**

Add these lines to your /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# I used a private IP for my example.  You'll have to get your
# specific IP from your internet provider.  If you are provided
# with a static IP they will also give you your specific gateway
# and network mask.  The DNS server is a public courtesy provision
# of Google.

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.101
  netmask 255.255.255.
  network 192.168.1.0
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
  post-up /sbin/route add default gw 192.168.1.1 eth0
```

**Dynamic IP configuration**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: I asked an almost identical question here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391561/network-access-ssh-and-ping-lost-when-logged-out) , but this solution did not work. If you want to help, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Works! However on recent `ubuntu` versions, `eth0` is apparently not a thing anymore. It now seems to be a model-specific name (it still shows up in `ifconfig` so no problem there)