# Network access (ssh and ping) lost when logged out

Tags: networking, network-manager

My host (5.4.0-97-generic Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) responds to ping and allows ssh when my user is logged in, remotely or locally. However, if I restart or log out all user sessions, I lose ssh access and it no longer responds to ICMP requests.

This behaviour started a few weeks ago after I remotely updated and restarted the host. I used to be able to login without any users logged in. I have since come back to the office and installed more updates, but the problem persists.

My firewall is set to public mode (I have a public IP) and explicitly allows SSH.

I tried specifying the IP settings (auto settings) as [answered in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682033/linux-server-only-gets-ip-config-after-first-logon) but it didn't work after restarting.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

My public IP is semi-static.

Here is the output of `/etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Here's what Network Manager has:
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you show us your netplan configuration. /etc/netplan/*.yaml

Comment: I added what you wanted :-)

Comment: I recommend to stop network manager and set in place a real netplan yaml file. Here you can find some examples https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Netplan/

Comment: That did the trick. Would you like to answer the question? Or should I answer it myself with the netplan yaml I used?
I am disappointed that NetworkManager changed it's behaviour after an update though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use a netplan yaml file with renderer networkd.

Here is the default after installation.

01-netplan.yaml

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens32:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "Make available to other users" in your screenshot is not enabled, so when you are not logged in, that network configuration is not active.